Intel PIN, get memory access value of SIMD, standard and multi-memory access instructions
I have been trying to write an Intel PIN tool for instruction tracing. In that, I want to also store the value accessed by a memory access.
The code below is the loop that I wrote for instrumenting memory accesses.
for(UINT32 memop_idx=0;memop_idx<memOperands;++memop_idx)
  {
      UINT32 op_idx=INS_MemoryOperandIndexToOperandIndex(ins,memop_idx);

      UINT32 scale = INS_OperandMemoryScale(ins,op_idx);
      INT32 disp = INS_OperandMemoryDisplacement(ins,op_idx);

      REG base_reg_full = REG_FullRegName(base_reg);
      REG index_reg_full= REG_FullRegName(index_reg);

      uint32_t op_header = OP_HEADER_MEM
                      | (INS_MemoryOperandIsRead(ins,memop_idx)<<OP_HEADER_READ_SHIFT)
                      | (INS_MemoryOperandIsWritten(ins,memop_idx)<<OP_HEADER_WRITE_SHIFT)
                      | ((INS_RegWContain(ins,base_reg))<<OP_HEADER_BASE_UPDATE_SHIFT)
                      | ((INS_RegWContain(ins,index_reg))<<OP_HEADER_INDEX_UPDATE_SHIFT)
                      | ((REG_is_any_vector_reg(base_reg))<<OP_HEADER_BASE_VECTOR_SHIFT)
                      | ((REG_is_any_vector_reg(index_reg))<<OP_HEADER_INDEX_VECTOR_SHIFT);
      

      INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)AddMemOp,
            IARG_UINT32,op_header,
            IARG_UINT32,base_reg,
            IARG_UINT32,index_reg,
            IARG_UINT32,base_reg_full,
            IARG_UINT32,index_reg_full,
            IARG_UINT32,scale,
            IARG_UINT32,disp,
            IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA,
            IARG_END);
  }

I noticed that the IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA does not ask for the memory operand index. So, I will probably have to put it outside the loop.
Down below are my queries

In the case where there are multiple memory accesses, how do I ensure I am not doing INS_InsertCall for an operand that will anyway be taken care by IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA?

To my knowledge, only instructions with an implicit memory operand can have multiple-memory accesses (So, almost 2). If it is correct, I can use INS_OperandIsImplicit to identify the operand that is taken care by IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA.

Is it possible to not use IARG_MULTI_MEMORYACCESS_EA at all even for gather/scatter instructions to get the values read/written by the instruction?



SIMD gathers can access multiple separate locations (and AVX-512 scatters if you care about stores).  See What x86 instructions take two (or more) memory operands? - yes, the other instructions are things like rep movsb and push qword [mem].  But there's also movdir64b which takes two separate addresses, not exactly implicitly: one is from a choice of register, the other is from a full addressing mode.  I haven't used Pin other than via SDE, so I don't know the answers to your questions, though.

@PeterCordes Do instructions have at most one multi element access memory operand?

Yes, the only ones I can think of with multiple discontiguous accesses from the same operand are gather, scatter, and the Xeon Phi only prefetch-gather (AVX512PF).  Instructions like rep movsb and rep[n]e cmpsb access two contiguous arrays of arbitrary length.
